# Bitmap resulting null even for particular path

Tags: android, bitmap, android-adapterview

I'm working on getting image from the camera and gallery. I'm trying to get the bitmap of the image to reduce the size of the image. But the bitmapfactory is null when I tried debugging the process. I'm not understanding why it is so even for absolute uri. I'm implementing inside adapter.

```
@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
public class PSAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Message> mMessages;



    public PSAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Message> messages) {
        super();
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mMessages = messages;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mMessages.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {       
        return mMessages.get(position);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Message message = (Message) this.getItem(position);

        ViewHolder holder; 
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.sms, parent, false);
            holder.message = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            holder.picture = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chat_image);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        if(message.message==null){
            holder.message.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.picture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Bitmap attachment = getScaledBitmap("content://media/external/images/media/4391", 800, 800);
            holder.picture.setImageBitmap(attachment);
        }else{
            holder.message.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.picture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.message.setText(message.getMessage());
        }
        LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) holder.message.getLayoutParams();

        if(message.isStatusMessage())
        {
            holder.message.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
            lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
            holder.message.setTextColor(R.color.textFieldColor);
        }
        else
        {       

            if(message.isMine())
            {
                holder.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.speech_bubble_green);
                lp.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
            }

            else
            {
                holder.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.speech_bubble_orange);
                lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
            }
            holder.message.setLayoutParams(lp);
            holder.message.setTextColor(R.color.textColor); 
        }
        return convertView;
    }
    public static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView message;
        ImageView picture;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return 0;
    }

    private Bitmap getScaledBitmap(String picPath, int width, int height){
        BitmapFactory.Options sizeOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        sizeOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picPath,sizeOptions);

        int inSampleSize = imageSize(sizeOptions, width, height);

        sizeOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        sizeOptions.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picPath, sizeOptions);
    }

    private int imageSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight){
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int size = 1;

        if(height>reqHeight || width>reqWidth){
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float)height/(float)reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float)width/(float)reqWidth);


            size = heightRatio<widthRatio? heightRatio:widthRatio;
        }
        return size;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you add read write permission for it in your Manifest file?

Comment: Yes. If I try using setImageUri, then it will show the images.

Comment: have you validated that your path is correct? besides that, id move th scaling to a background thread